# Converting between QObject* and void*

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, casting

I'm using QT 5.7 and, because of the libraries I have to use, I need to convert a QObject ('s derived class) to and from a void pointer.

A couple of definitions. I have a function that accepts only a void pointer, and my class derives from QObject:

```
void oneFunction(void *obj);

class MyObj : public QObject
{
    ...
};
```

Then I create and fill an object:

```
MyObj *ptr = new MyObj(parent);
ptr->.......
```

At some point I convert it to a void pointer, because I have to pass it to the function. This cast is done automatically:

```
oneFunction(ptr);
```

Then, after some time, I receive back the pointer I passed, and I need to convert it back to the original class. The pointer was not modified by the function:

```
void callbackFromOneFunction(void *theOldPointer)
{
    MyObj *oldPtr = qobject_cast<MyObj*>(static_cast<QObject*>(theOldPointer));
    if (oldPtr != nullptr)
    {
        ... Now it's back, so use it
    }
}
```

Now, is this whole procedure right? Is there some problem/leak you spot? Is there a better solution?

Thank you

Comment: If you convert from `MyObj*` to `void*` with an implicit conversion, you need to `static_cast` back to `MyObj*`, not to `QObject*`. Round-tripping is only guaranteed if the types are exactly the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think a single `static_cast` is enough.

`static_cast` doesn't check the type at runtime and should be used when you're sure the type is okay. In this case you're sure, and you won't need `qobject_cast`. `qobject_cast` checks the type at runtime (it's similar to `dynamic_cast`).

---

#### In case of target type being known

A `static_cast` or C-style cast is okay. Although C-style cast works fine here, it's not recommended because:

- C-style casts are't checked by compiler whereas `static_cast`s are.
- `static_cast`s are far more readable and can be searched for more easily.
- [More info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/256138).

#### In case of target type being unknown

- When the source type is `QObject *` or its derivations, a single `qobject_cast` is enough.
- If the source type is polymorphic, `dynamic_cast` is used. In other words, `dynamic_cast` is used *only* for polymorphic source types (i.e. classes having at least one virtual function). In such classes, at compile-time we can't determine the most derived type of pointers which point to base classes having virtual methods, only at runtime we can determine them.

  About dynamic casting `void*`,  it's allowed to cast to but not cast from.

In your case `void*` doesn't have any [RTTI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-time_type_information), so neither `qobject_cast` nor `dynamic_cast` can be used.

Comment: The problem with solution 2 (only `qobject_cast`) is that `qobject_cast` expects a `QObject*`, not a `void*`, so a single one is not enough

Comment: C-style cast should be avoided.

Comment: @rubenvb You're right. `static_cast` is preferable over C-style cast for sake of readability and being checked by compiler. updated my answer.

Comment: They're also not equivalent: a C style cast is still radically different from any c++ cast, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/256138).

Comment: @rubenvb I didn't say they are equivalent. I said both casts work, even through it's highly recommended to not use C-style cast in C++.

Answer (score 3):

*If* **and** only *if* you are certain the pointer was not and will never be touched by `oneFunction(void*)` in ways that are [Undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviours-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-a), then its safe to cast receive that pointer elsewhere in *your* program and type-cast it back to `QObject`. See [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_void).

In that case, this is perfectly valid:

```
void callbackFromOneFunction(void *theOldPointer)
{
    MyObj *oldPtr = qobject_cast<MyObj*>(static_cast<QObject*>(theOldPointer));
    if (oldPtr != nullptr)
    {
        ... Now it's back, so use it
    }
}
```